# Not able to upload apk to testdroid

Tags: api, cloud, appium, testdroid, bitbar

curl -H "Accept: application/json" -u username:password -F myAppFile=@"path to apk" http://appium.bitbar.com/upload

com.testdroid.api.APIException: Failed to acquire access token. Reason: cloud.bitbar.com

Comment: It is fixed already

Answer (score 0):

Since Jan 2019 you can also just upload your file to the file API endpoint directly. Check on [Bitbar documentation](http://docs.bitbar.com/testing/appium/client-side/index.html#upload-your-app-to-cloud)